# ELB log interpretation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have been trying to solve a Gateway timeout error (504) 
[504 Gateway Timeout ELB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235810/504-gateway-timeout-elb)
and when i turned the AWS ELB  logs i get this for the request that timed out.

```
2018-11-09T22:32:23.016245Z bvt-AppServerLB-POI9R2HYQG67M 10.90.6.224:63629 - -1 -1 -1 504 0 1321 0 "POST https://xxxx.xxxxxxx.com:443/exec/scenario HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
```

Question is

1. Can we say from these log entry whether it is the server that timedout or did the client timeout while connected to ELB???. I am understanding that ELB maintains two connections one to ec2 instance (server ) and other to the client .
2. What are those -1 's in the log mean ?

Please help as this will assist  me to narrow down the problem area.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR From the log you posted, it's either the instance registered to the load balancer is not responding fast enough and the ELB idle timeout is triggering or the instance is closing the connection before the idle timeout.

[Raise the idle timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html) on the ELB and see if that cures this.

The first `-` corresponds to `backend:port`

> If the load balancer can't send the request to a registered instance, or if the instance closes the connection before a response can be sent, this value is set to -.
>   This value can also be set to - if the registered instance does not respond before the idle timeout.

The three `-1`'s in the log correspond to `request_processing_time, backend_processing_time, and response_processing_time` respectively.

**request_processing_time**

> This value is set to -1 if the load balancer can't dispatch the request to a registered instance. This can happen if the registered instance closes the connection before the idle timeout or if the client sends a malformed request. Additionally, for TCP listeners, this can happen if the client establishes a connection with the load balancer but does not send any data.
>   This value can also be set to -1 if the registered instance does not respond before the idle timeout.

**backend_processing_time**

> This value is set to -1 if the load balancer can't dispatch the request to a registered instance. This can happen if the registered instance closes the connection before the idle timeout or if the client sends a malformed request.
>   This value can also be set to -1 if the registered instance does not respond before the idle timeout.

**response_processing_time**

> This value is set to -1 if the load balancer can't dispatch the request to a registered instance. This can happen if the registered instance closes the connection before the idle timeout or if the client sends a malformed request.
>   This value can also be set to -1 if the registered instance does not respond before the idle timeout.

See links below for more details.

**References**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/